# Closing Windows Media Player, after hanging, with the task manager caused PC to hang

Tags: freeze, windows-media-player, task-manager

If I'm not mistaken, this topic has not yet been addressed elsewhere.

The situation is as follows:

- Occasionally, Windows Media Player freezes and I have to close it using the Task Manager.
- After closing it, my computer goes into complete freeze mode, it no longer responds to any key stroke.
- My only solution now is to shut down the computer by holding the power button 5 seconds.

I have Googled my ass off before, tried virus scans but I'm out of ideas by now. So I come to the place where all the experts are.

I am using:

- Windows XP Professional Version 2002 SP3
- Windows Media Player version 11.0.5721.5280

Best regards
Clint

If you need any additional information please let me know.

Comment: Hi Clint, this site is for programming-related questions.  I'm voting to move this to SuperUser.com

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for misplacing the topic. I'm curious if anyone here will know what the problem may be.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, some "multi-media" keyboards contains extra buttons such as Voluem Up/Down. These keys work with Windows Media Player, but not always perfectly. It appears that in some cases after closing WMP, all buttons (and not just those for media functions) can stop working.

In this case, the mouse will still work. If your mouse doesn't work either, don't blame the keyboard.